# How to insert a new line into database and read value onto my webgrid in razor MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am using Razor, MVC3 with Poco entities.

While inserting into the database I am using **Enviroment.NewLine** as a seperator between two texts.

```
  oldValues += " Name = '" + oldName.Name + "'" + Environment.NewLine ;
  oldValues += " Age = '" + oldName.Age + "'" + Environment.NewLine ;
```

I am then assigning this **oldValues string object** to one of my columns in the database.

But when I am reading this value onto my **webgrid**, the formatting does not appear as expected.

What could be the problem here ?

Please suggest me some methods, I have also tried appending

```
  <br />
```

tags too.

**Expected Output in one of my webgrid column:**

Old Values are

Name = Yasser

Age = 24

and New Values are

Name = Yasser R

Age =25

**Actual Output in one of my webgrid column:**

Old Values are Name = Yasser Age = 24 and New Values are Name = Yasser R Age =25

Comment: What are you expecting, and what are you getting?

Comment: I have updated my question with that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the behavior of HTML. You can wrap your text with `<pre>Your String Here</pre>` and it should display the text as you're expecting it.

Comment: can I apply this <pre> tag only to one of my webgrid column ??

Answer (score 0):

With some help from Paul, I have managed to solve this problem

here is what I am using now

```
 logGrid.Column(header: "Message", columnName: "Message", format: @<pre>@item.Message </pre>),
```